# How to close tab when content is displayed in new window in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I have this context menu with option to display tab content into new window and closing TabPane tab:

```
MenuItem item5 = new MenuItem("Open Tab In Stand-Alone Window");
        item5.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("Open Tab In Stand-Alone Window");
                Node test = tab.getContent();

                NavMenu.standAloneTab(test);
                tabPane.getTabs().remove(tab);

            }
        });
```

The new dialog with tab content:

```
public static void standAloneTab(Node tab)
    {
        final int xSize = 640;
        final int ySize = 480;
        final Color backgroundColor = Color.WHITESMOKE;

        Stage newConnDialog = new Stage();
        newConnDialog.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20));

        grid.add(tab, 0, 0);

        Scene aboutDialogScene = new Scene(grid, xSize, ySize, backgroundColor);
        newConnDialog.setScene(aboutDialogScene);
        newConnDialog.show();
    }
```

When I select `Open Tab In Stand-Alone Window` new window appears with the content of the tab but the old tab is not closed. If I call `tabPane.getTabs().remove(tab);` to close the tab the new window is empty.

How I can close the tab without deleting the content?

***EDIT***

I updated the code this way:

```
MenuItem item5 = new MenuItem("Open Tab in Stand-alone Window");
    item5.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("Open Tab In Stand-Alone Window");
            Node openedTab = tab.getContent();

            NavMenu.standAloneTab(tabPane, openedTab);
            //tabPane.getTabs().remove(tab);

        }
    });
```

And the new dialog:

```
public static void standAloneTab(final TabPane tabPane, final Node tab)
    {

        Stage newConnDialog = new Stage();
        newConnDialog.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);

        newConnDialog.setOnShown(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(WindowEvent t)
            {
                tabPane.getTabs().remove(tab);
            }
        });

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20));

        grid.add(tab, 0, 0);

        Scene aboutDialogScene = new Scene(grid, 700, 500, Color.WHITESMOKE);
        newConnDialog.setScene(aboutDialogScene);
        newConnDialog.show();
    }
```

I updated the code but I get the same result.

Comment: You are passing the content of the tab (openedTab variable is the content of the tab) to the standAloneTab method. And you are trying to remove the content from the tabs. However you should remove the tab itself from the tabPane, not the content of it. Give it a try...

Comment: `You are passing the content of the tab (openedTab variable is the content of the tab) to the standAloneTab method. And you are trying to remove the content from the tabs.` Yes

Comment: However, you HAVE TO give a ***Tab*** object to tabPane.getTabs().remove(...) method, not some other ***Node*** object, to be able to remove the tab. It is definitely wrong, you cannot remove the tab in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling `tabPane.getTabs().remove(tab);` as

```
newConnDialog.setOnShown(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(WindowEvent t) {
        tabPane.getTabs().remove(tab);
    }
});
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

how to close other tabs except the selected tab using the contex menus??

```
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Tabs");
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 250, Color.WHITE);

        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Tab tab = new Tab();
            tab.setText("Tab" + i);
            HBox hbox = new HBox();
            hbox.getChildren().add(new Label("Tab" + i));
            hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            tab.setContent(hbox);
            tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);

            ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
            MenuItem close = new MenuItem();
            MenuItem closeOthers = new MenuItem();
            MenuItem closeAll = new MenuItem();

            close.setText("Close");
            closeOthers.setText("Close Others");
            closeAll.setText("Close All");
            contextMenu.getItems().addAll(close,closeOthers,closeAll);
            tab.setContextMenu(contextMenu);

            ObservableList<Tab> tablist = tabPane.getTabs();


            close.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event)
                {
                    tabPane.getTabs().remove(tabPane.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
                }
            });

            closeOthers.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event)
                {
                    tabPane.getTabs().removeAll();
                }
            });

            closeAll.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event)
                {
                    tabPane.getTabs().removeAll(tablist);
                }
            });
        }

        // bind to take available space
        borderPane.prefHeightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());
        borderPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());

        borderPane.setCenter(tabPane);
        root.getChildren().add(borderPane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```